# iOS Networking Library Suggestion

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, networking

I would some suggestion about the choose of an iOS networking library for my app.

My needs are:

1. Send asynchronous request (GET and POST) and if the network is down display a `UIAlertView` to inform the user of the error.
2. Send simple synchronous request (GET) and if the network is down do the same of the above point.

Does anyone have some lib to suggest? (except ASIHTTPRequest that is no longer supported) Possibly, if this lib have some nice doc is better. I'm an iOS beginner.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard good things about RestKit https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit

There is a good list of alternatives at the bottom of this blog post. http://allseeing-i.com/[request_release];

I've only used ASIHTTPRequest before, and even though it's not longer being developed by Ben Copsey, it looks like he's still merging pull requests and stuff. It's in use by so many people, I wouldn't be surprised if the community picks it up. It will probably be safe for at least another version of iOS.

Comment: RestKit is a bit different from ASI - it's more of a sync framework for automatically converting JSON responses into object graphs. It's definitely overkill for what the OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a library for this.

To send a synchronous GET request:

```
//set up the GET URL and params
NSURL *getURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somesite.com/somepath?foo=bar"];

//create the request
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:getURL];

//get the response
NSError *error = nil;
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

To send a synchronous POST request:

```
//set up the POST URL and params
NSURL *postURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somesite.com/somepath"];
NSString *postParams = @"foo=bar&hello=world";

//create the request - this bit is the same for every post
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:postURL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSData *data = [postParams dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[self addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[self setHTTPBody:data];

//get the response
NSError *error = nil;
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

In either case if responseData is nil or error is not nil, present an alert using the following:

```
[[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease] show];
```

Comment: Don't forget that you need to escape your parameters. Otherwise things like '&' in arguments will break the variable parsing.

Comment: Good point. I've written a handy mini-library for creating URL-safe query strings (avoiding the well-documented problems with using the stringByAddingPercentEscaping: method): https://github.com/nicklockwood/URLUtils

Comment: What happened to this link, Nick?

Comment: Sorry, I renamed it. You can now find it at https://github.com/nicklockwood/RequestUtils

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the question he is also looking for asynchronous requests.

I would suggest AFNetworking or GCNetworkKit (the last one is my own). Both libraries are very easy to use and yet powerful.

I don't think AFNetworking provides a synchronous network request though. Well at least mine doesn't. You shouldn't do that anyway.
Both libraries support error handling. There should be no problem on implementing an UIAlertView.

You can find them on GitHub. Just search for them. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I looked for AFNetworking and I saw how to use it. But I'm still not find how to handle error (like no internet connection). Did you know some references for doing that?

Comment: Error handling is pretty easy in AFNetworking. Take a look at this https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperation.h . The last method :)

Comment: should I use that method for handle when there's not internet connection and displays an alert? thanks man.

Comment: Fred, try googling for Apple's Reachability example. That provides a good solution for detecting and handling no-network scenarios.